# Preprocessing csv files to use with tflearn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, neural-network, tflearn

My question is about preprocessing csv files before inputing them into a neural network.

I want to build a deep neural network for the famous iris dataset using tflearn in python 3.

Dataset:  http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data

I'm using tflearn to load the csv file. However, the classes column of my data set has words such as iris-setosa, iris-versicolor, iris-virginica.

Nueral networks work only with numbers. So, I have to find a way to change the classes from words to numbers. Since it is a very small dataset, I can do it manually using Excel/text editor. I manually assigned numbers for different classes.

But, I can't possibly do it for every dataset I work with. So, I tried using pandas to perform one hot encoding.

```
preprocess_data = pd.read_csv("F:\Gautam\.....\Dataset\iris_data.csv")
preprocess_data = pd.get_dummies(preprocess_data)
```

But now, I can't use this piece of code:

```
data, labels = load_csv('filepath', categorical_labels=True,
                     n_classes=3)
```

'filepath' should only be a directory to the csv file, not any variable like preprocess_data.

Original Dataset:

```
     Sepal Length  Sepal Width  Petal Length  Petal Width  Class
89            5.5          2.5           4.0          1.3  iris-versicolor
85            6.0          3.4           4.5          1.6  iris-versicolor
31            5.4          3.4           1.5          0.4  iris-setosa
52            6.9          3.1           4.9          1.5  iris-versicolor
111           6.4          2.7           5.3          1.9  iris-virginica
```

Manually modified dataset:

```
     Sepal Length  Sepal Width  Petal Length  Petal Width  Class
89            5.5          2.5           4.0          1.3      1
85            6.0          3.4           4.5          1.6      1
31            5.4          3.4           1.5          0.4      0
52            6.9          3.1           4.9          1.5      1
111           6.4          2.7           5.3          1.9      2
```

Here's my code which runs perfectly, but, I have modified the dataset manually.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.data_utils import load_csv


data_source = 'F:\Gautam\.....\Dataset\iris_data.csv'

data, labels = load_csv(data_source, categorical_labels=True,
                         n_classes=3)


network = input_data(shape=[None, 4], name='InputLayer')

network = fully_connected(network, 9, activation='sigmoid', name='Hidden_Layer_1')

network = fully_connected(network, 3, activation='softmax', name='Output_Layer')

network = regression(network, batch_size=1, optimizer='sgd', learning_rate=0.2)

model = tflearn.DNN(network)
model.fit(data, labels, show_metric=True, run_id='iris_dataset', validation_set=0.1, n_epoch=2000)
```

I want to know if there's any other built-in function in tflearn (or in any other module, for that matter) that I can use to modify the value of my classes from words to numbers. I don't think manually modifying the datasets would be productive.

I'm a beginner in tflearn and neural networks also. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use label encoder from `sklearn` library:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder

df = pd.read_csv('iris_data.csv',header=None)
df.columns=[Sepal Length,Sepal Width,Petal Length,Petal Width,Class]

enc=LabelEncoder()
df['Class']=enc.fit_transform(df['Class'])
print df.head(5)
```

if you want `One-hot encoding` then first you need to labelEncode then do OneHotEncoding :

```
enc=LabelEncoder()
enc_1=OneHotEncoder()
df['Class']=enc.fit_transform(df['Class'])
df['Class']=enc_1.fit_transform([df['Class']]).toarray()
print df.head(5)
```

These encoders first sort the words in alphabetical order then assign them labels. If you want to see which label is assigned to which class, do:

```
for k in list(enc.classes_) :
   print 'name ::{}, label ::{}'.format(k,enc.transform([k]))
```

If you want to save this dataframe as a csv file, do:

```
df.to_csv('Processed_Irisdataset.csv',sep=',')
```

Comment: LabelEncoder works great. However, OneHotEncoder returns a 'value error'. ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Iris-virginica'. Thanks.

Comment: @GautamJ - hmmm, so map solution is not better for you? Why? I am curious :)

Comment: @PratikKumar, another ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead. But I think I can manage with LabelEncoding alone. It works fine. Do you think it would be necessary to use one hot encoding?

Comment: Label encoding is sufficient for output labels, if features were words then one-hot becomes necessary. as far as the roor is concerned look carefully `enc_1.fit_transform([df['Class']])`, df['Class'] is surrounded by a pair of square-brackets

Comment: @PratikKumar, Ooops... I missed the square brackets... But now, I have another problem... The newly created csv file has an extra column (the '0' th column) of numbers from 0, 1, 2... for each row. It does not have any header though. Any ideas on how to delete that column??? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest solution is `map` by `dict` of all possible values:

```
df['Class'] = df['Class'].map({'iris-versicolor': 1, 'iris-setosa': 0, 'iris-virginica': 2})
print (df)
   Sepal Length  Sepal Width  Petal Length  Petal  Width  Class
0            89          5.5           2.5    4.0    1.3      1
1            85          6.0           3.4    4.5    1.6      1
2            31          5.4           3.4    1.5    0.4      0
3            52          6.9           3.1    4.9    1.5      1
4           111          6.4           2.7    5.3    1.9      2
```

If want generate `dictionary` by all unique values:

```
d = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(df['Class'].unique())}
print (d)
{'iris-versicolor': 0, 'iris-virginica': 2, 'iris-setosa': 1}

df['Class'] = df['Class'].map(d)
print (df)
   Sepal Length  Sepal Width  Petal Length  Petal  Width  Class
0            89          5.5           2.5    4.0    1.3      0
1            85          6.0           3.4    4.5    1.6      0
2            31          5.4           3.4    1.5    0.4      1
3            52          6.9           3.1    4.9    1.5      0
4           111          6.4           2.7    5.3    1.9      2
```