# Convert Date dataframe with one-hot encoder

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, neural-network

Sample data for  training 
[image]

I'm working on ANN model using Keras to predict crimes in San Francisco using the dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/c/sf-crime. From the dataset above, I want to convert DayOfWeek into binary of weekDay(Mon-Fri) as 0 and weekEnd(Sat-Sun) as 1, each month to categorical values of seasons (Winter, Spring, Summer, Authumn). How do I replace or apply it using the lambda function or pandas? Any suggestion to one-hot encode the Hour values?

Answer (score 0):

let's say you have the data stored in a dataFrame `df`, and day-of-week is stored at `df['week']`. Then simplest solution could be

```
mapping_dict={'sunday':1,'monday':0,'Tuesday':0,'wednesday':0,'Thursday':0,'friday':0,'saturday':1}

df['week']=df['week'].map(mapping_dict)
```

Referred from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50129485/preprocessing-csv-files-to-use-with-tflearn#answer-50129593)